# Google Chrome and Helvetica Neue, big bug

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts, rendering

I'm experiencing a big, bad bug only with Google Chrome. I have all the Helvetica fonts installed on my Windows 7 computer. (Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica Neue LT, and so on.. it's like more than 50 different styles of Helvetica).

However, when I visit a web page using Helvetica Neue, my fonts get mad, as the following screenshot shows:
[image: chrome screenshot]

This is instead what I can see with Firefox, the font is much cleaner:
[image: firefox screenshot]

I tried uninstalling all of the fonts named Helvetica-something, even using Unlocker because the system wouldn't let me delete them, then reinstalled them all. Nothing absolutely changed on Chrome.

Any help in order to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you reboot after re-installing the fonts? Usually you'd want to uninstall them in safe mode if they're in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has written that [installing Helvetica Neue Fonts with Google Chrome on Windows considered harmful](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingHelveticaNeueFontsWithGoogleChromeOnWindowsConsideredHarmful.aspx):

> However, Helvetica is super common font that is mentioned in Stylesheets - often explicitly when CSS is designed on a Mac - and Arial on Windows usually steps in as the replacement on Windows.
>
> The Helvetica Neue font that I installed for my presentation is very poorly hinted (if at all) at small sizes like the one's being used. It's just not a Web Font, and while it's great for the giant sizes I needed for my talk, it's lousy for the web.
>
> Both IE and Chrome were picking up that my system had a Helvetica available on the system and used it instead. The Stylesheet said "hey, gimme Helvetica" and the browser said "Cool, here's one."