# Why does "Helvetica Neue" render poorly on my Windows 7, latest version of Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, fonts

So here is a screenshot of how poor "Helvetica Neue" is rendering for me on my Windows 7 PC, Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86, a simple file HTML page, note the location bar URL in the image:

[image]

And here is the entire HTML file:

```
<h4 style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';">Helvetica Neue:</h4>
<div style="width: 500px;color:#000;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius at esse nonumy similique, 
    ea quo erat mollis. Quo mucius legendos appellantur et. Eum cetero verterem cu. 
    Ex mei stet dolorum, mei perpetua disputando in. Mei affert eruditi consetetur et, 
    has in sumo fugit scaevola. Te eros illud veniam quo, minimum antiopam eu mei.
</div>

<br />
<h4 style="font-family: Helvetica">Helvetica</h4>
<div style="width: 500px;color:#000;font-family: Helvetica">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius at esse nonumy similique, 
    ea quo erat mollis. Quo mucius legendos appellantur et. Eum cetero verterem cu. 
    Ex mei stet dolorum, mei perpetua disputando in. Mei affert eruditi consetetur et, 
    has in sumo fugit scaevola. Te eros illud veniam quo, minimum antiopam eu mei.
</div>
<h4 style="font-family: NotAFont">NotAFont</h4>
<div style="width: 500px;color:#000;font-family: NotAFont">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius at esse nonumy similique, 
    ea quo erat mollis. Quo mucius legendos appellantur et. Eum cetero verterem cu. 
    Ex mei stet dolorum, mei perpetua disputando in. Mei affert eruditi consetetur et, 
    has in sumo fugit scaevola. Te eros illud veniam quo, minimum antiopam eu mei.
</div>
```

I do not have "Helvetica Neue" installed on my Windows 7 computer under C:\Windows\Fonts:

[image]

Using Font Expert to delve deeper, as c:\Windows\Fonts does not always show all installed fonts there is still no "Helvetica Neue" font installed:

[image]

Helvetica Neue does not show under chrome://settings/fonts:

[image]

The font-family rendered is indeed "Helvetica Neue" according to Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

You can see that the Helvetica renders fine, no surprises there, and here is the Computed Tab of Chrome for Helvetica:

[image]

Here you can see my Chrome settings will default "Times New Roman" if the font does not exist and there is no other fonts in the CSS font-family:

[image]

Here we see Helvetica Neue renders fine on El Capitan Mac Safari:

[image]

Here is the same issue using a completely clean history, settings, bookmarks, etc with "[New Chrome Session](https://bitbucket.org/bradisbell/new-chrome-session/src)":

[image]

And you can see in the New Chrome Session Developer Tools that the Computed Font for "Helvetica Neue" is still Helvetica Neue:

[image]

Here is Firefox on my machine, it says the Computed font for "Helvetica Neue" is Helvetica Neue though at least the font is rendered clear and readable, and, not surprisingly is the same font as "NotAFont", this means the Computed column of Firefox Developer tools does not tell you the actual font used like Chrome Developer tools does :

[image]

My DPI is 96, my screen resolution is 1920 x 1080.

So it is proven the font-face is not installed in the Windows/Fonts directory on my machine and also proven that the font is not being delivered to me from the a server in the form of a .woff, .ttf, .eot, or .svg file.

Solutions I have attempted:

1) Adding the following to  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css:

`@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }`

References to first solution I attempted
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/J4dqHZD3dcs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjk1dAR0Z5w

2) Adding the following to my my file based test.html page I am using in this question:

```
<style>
  html, body {
        text-rendering: optimizeSpeed !important;
}
</style>
```

Reference for solution 2)
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/J4dqHZD3dcs

An interesting suggestion in the comments of this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingHelveticaNeueFontsWithGoogleChromeOnWindowsConsideredHarmful.aspx

> It's because you use Helvetica Neue wich is meant for print not for web display. Go buy yourself a Helvetica font that is actually meant for web - Neue Haas Grotesk. This is Helvetica done right for web ;)

Is it true "Helvetica Neue" is meant for print? If so, why is it so prevalent in web design?

**How is it possible that Chrome Developer Tools Computed tab says that the computed font is "Helvetica Neue"?**

**Since Chrome is finding "Helvetica Neue" somewhere, why is it so poorly rendered?**

Comment: Does Helvetica Neue show in `chrome://settings/fonts`?

Comment: Hi @Vinayak, no "Helvetica Neue" does not show under chrome://settings/fonts, I added a screenshot to my question so you can see.

Comment: Could you use [NewChromeSession](https://bitbucket.org/bradisbell/new-chrome-session) and load that bit of HTML and see if the first paragraph is still rendered as Helvetica Neue?

Comment: @Vinayak it is still rendered "Helvetica Neue" using New Chrome Session, I added screenshots of NewChromeSession to my question

Comment: Hmmm... this makes me wonder if Chrome is taking the Helvetica font and just making it smaller and calling it "Neue" thus explaining this poor rendering. I know that's how it handles bold fonts if you don't actually have the bold font family (which also looks fuzzy and awful) , but I didn't think the keyword "Neue" should set off a similar behavior. Can you temporarily uninstall Helvetica and see if that's the cause?

Comment: You say it is “proven that the font is not being delivered to me from the a server”, but where is the proof? Are you _sure_ that there’s nothing (such as an extension) in your installation downloading missing fonts? What do you see on the Resources tab of Dev Tools?

Comment: Very odd that one Dev Tools screenshot shows 471 glyphs being rendered in Helvetica Neue, while another shows 296; are these for the same sample?

Comment: Support for Custom.css was removed from Chrome a long time ago, so unless it’s been reinstated since (which AFAICT it has not), solution 1 will not work. Possibly related (though I’m not convinced it really got answered satisfactorily): http://superuser.com/questions/719907

Comment: Do you get different results if you disable DirectWrite rendering? chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write

Comment: @Brian Nixon the proof that the font is not being delivered by the server is that I am showing the entire code of the HTML page, look at the very first screen shot and then the HTML code, this is my HTML file, I control it, I am not including any web font files, the file is local file based,I am showing the entire code, there is no style sheet references or javascript references

Comment: @Brian Nixon, yes the screen shots are of the same Lorem Ipsum text, I just double checked, that is strange that the rendered Glyph count is different at all, I don't have a good enough understanding to guess as to why though

Comment: @Brian Nixon, so I already had DirectWrite disabled, enabling it gives me the same results

Comment: Have you have Helvetica (not Helvetica Neue) in Windows fonts? http://superuser.com/questions/579749/google-chrome-and-helvetica-neue-big-bug

Comment: Yes I have Helvetica installed in Windows Fonts, you can see that Helvetica is rendering correctly in the first screenshot and I have a screenshot of Windows Fonts showing Helvetica installed

Comment: "The font-family rendered is indeed "Helvetica Neue" according to Chrome Developer Tools:" is incorrect, it clearly shows a font stack with a fallback to "helvetica" and it also has a font-weight of "normal". Helvetica, typically, has a "very light" font weight, which resembles what your capture is showing. So it appears as though it is using the first matching helvetica. The question then becomes "why chrome calculating a font-stack unlike the other examples?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your FontExpert screenshot it shows that you have two Helvetica fonts installed. 
Have you tried temporarily removing one or both of them ?

You don't have a font called 'Last Resort' , do you ?

Do you have the same issue in Chrome Canary and Opera 34 ?

The two GPF topics you referenced are rather old - 
have you read some of the newer topics in https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearch/%22helvetica$20neue%22 ?

Comment: No I haven't temporarily removed all Helvetica fonts installed, I could try this, though I do need Helvetica so I would have to reinstall I think. I removed one of the two Helvetica fonts though.

Comment: Haven't tested in Chrome Canary and Opera 34 though I am not sure what information would be that helpful from doing so...

Comment: You suggest to search GPF for newer topics was a good one thanks

Comment: The bounty for this question has expired, searching GPF for newer topics does result in at least one new potential solutions though I am on my Mac and not on my PC right now so I cannot test. Removing Helvetica entirely will probably work as well. So, thought I cannot say, this is the answer to the question definitely it was a helpful answer and so the bounty does not go to waste in the ether, I am giving it to you, Merry Christmas ;)